# due date estimating

Tags: sql, plsql

my `"insurance_pay_dtl"(insurance table)` consist `'ins_paid_dt'(insurance paid date)` column, 
  i need to select all members whoever not paid insurance amount before due date,
  due date is 1 year(365 days)
  how do i do..?

Comment: Is there a `due_date` column?

Comment: Post the table structure with same data

Comment: yes, due_date column is there on another table like insurance_farmer_hdr.

Comment: What about leap years?

Comment: convert last day and add +1

Comment: Is there any way to join the tables `insurance_farmer_hdr` and `insurance_pay_dtl`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link insurance_pay_dtl table with insurance_farmer_hdr with its primary key, for example:

```
Select member_id, member_name from insurance_farmer_hdr ifd, insurance_pay_dtl ipd
 where ifd.insurance_rec_id = ipd.insruance_rec_id and trunc(sysdate) > ifd.due_date
```

change the columns in above query as per your table columns and try.